# Tab background is not there in programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

How to set the tab background color dynamically? I had tried to get the **app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_background"** in the java code but I can't find please help me out friends I am using design library by google I had tried the custom view in the tab layout it worked but the gap is coming in between the tabs

[image: After using the custom view]

My code

```
 icon_tabs.addTab(icon_tabs.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.first_tab), true);
            icon_tabs.addTab(icon_tabs.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.second_tab));
            icon_tabs.addTab(icon_tabs.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.third_tab));
            icon_tabs.addTab(icon_tabs.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.fourth_tab));
            icon_tabs.addTab(icon_tabs.newTab().setCustomView(R.layout.five_tab));
```

My Layout for custom tab

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/first_tab_drawable">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/love_home" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: I need tab layout to be like this]

[image: when I select another tab it must be like this]

Comment: wt ur trying to do exactly ?

Comment: i had added the images please check it

Comment: What is the Java code you currently have? What class / library are you trying to use? Either way, `R.drawable.tab_background` should be available to use

Comment: i am not using any library and about drawable it can only set from the xml i had updating the java code

Comment: So you want change the tab background. Implement custom tabs with , drawables selected states and u should call selected on tab change state

Comment: Can you please some what briefly and getting confused please

Comment: Sir i had tried it worked but getting gap between the tabs @Sush

Comment: @sush i had updated my question please check it